# is there any replacement for the nodejs url.resolve function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodeJs provides the https://nodejs.org/api/url.html module which allows to:

- resolve two relative urls:

```js
require('url').resolve(`profile/user/99/details/`, `../../55/details/`) // -> 'profile/user/55/details/'
```

- resolve a relative url and an absolute url:

```js
require('url').resolve(`profile/user/99/details/`, `http://example.com`) // -> 'http://example.com/'
```

- resolve an absolute url and a relative url:

```js
require('url').resolve(`http://example.com`, `profile/user/99/details/`) // -> 'http://example.com/profile/user/99/details/'
```

- resolve two absolute urls:

```js
require('url').resolve(`http://example.com`, `https://stackoverflow.com`) // ->
'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

however `require('url').resolve` was deprecated

what would be the correct (as in non deprecated) way to resolve the urls like in the examples above?

Comment: have you tried the `path` module, `.resolve()` function ? Or as the docs say: " Deprecated: Use the WHATWG URL API instead." -> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html

Comment: `path.resolve` will always use the current working directory for relative urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For urls specific, you can use the `new URL()` constructor defined by the [WHATWG](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-class) standard.

```
// syntax
const url = new URL(url [, base]); // (url: string | URL, base?: string | URL) => URL
```

The `href` property holds the resolved url.

```js
console.log(new URL(`profile/user/99/details/`, `http://example.com`).href);
console.log(new URL(`https://stackoverflow.com`, `http://example.com`).href);
```

For paths, you can use the `path.posix.join()` function provided by Node.js to force joining the paths with forward slashes.

```js
const path = require("path");
path.posix.join(`profile/user/99/details/`, `../../55/details/`));
```

You could also combine the two.

```js
const path = require("path");
const joined = path.posix.join(`profile/user/99/details/`,"..", "..", `55/details/`);

// 'https://stackoverflow.com/profile/user/55/details/'
const { href } = new URL(joined, "https://stackoverflow.com");
```

Examples.

```js
const path = require("path");

// two relative paths => 'profile/user/55/details/'
path.posix.join("profile/user/99/details/", "../../55/details/");

// absolute and relative path (right) => 'http://example.com/profile/user/99/details/'
new URL("profile/user/99/details/", "http://example.com").href;

// absolute and relative path (wrong) => throws TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]
new URL("http://example.com", "profile/user/99/details/").href;

// two absolute paths => 'https://stackoverflow.com'
new URL("https://stackoverflow.com", "http://example.com").href;

// combined => 'http://example.com/profile/user/55/details'
new URL(path.posix.join(
    "profile", "user", "99", "details",
    "..", "..", "55", "details"
), "http://example.com").href;

// or 
new URL(path.posix.join(
    "profile/user/99/details/",
    "../../55/details"
), "http://example.com").href;
```

Comment: unfortunately the path.resolve example doesn't work

Comment: @jantimon updated my answer, `path.join()` is the function you need

Comment: Wow cool - I didn't know that `join` takes care of `..`

Comment: It does, even better practice is to use `path.join("a/b/c/", "..", "..", "z")` but both are fine.

Comment: does this also work well on windows?

Comment: Did some research, apparently, there is an option to only have a specific implementation of `path`, specifying `path.posix` will always return a path with forward slashes (updated the answer).

Comment: thank you so much - can I ask you for one more favour? could you please show an example for all 4 cases from the question?

Comment: @jantimon glad I could help, learned a few things from it myself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use build-in new URL() constructor:

```
new URL(`https://stackoverflow.com`, `http://example.com`)
```

returns:

```
 URL {
  href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
  origin: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  hostname: 'stackoverflow.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
 }
```

The problem with that:

1. Constructor takes the first arg as primary. So as you wished:
   `` resolve(`http://example.com`, `https://stackoverflow.com`)' `` would **not** return `https://stackoverflow.com`.
2. Returns whole class so you have to "collect" the .href only.

If you can use non-build-in methods, I would suggest
https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url .

Comment: I would definitely recommend using resolve-url package. It has over 15mil. downloads a week, and as the docs says: *Just like Node.js’ path.resolve/url.resolve for the browser.*

Comment: The package you mentioned is also deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url

Comment: Yeah, my bad, but why don't you want use the built-in URL constructor?

Comment: It doesn't work at all for relative urls (my first example)